# Access parameter without load function in svelte kit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In SvelteKit, I want to access page.params without using the SSR load function because I want to have client side rendering only. Is there any way to access page.params without the SSR load function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
import { page } from "$app/stores";
const { slug } = $page.params;
```

and in this way I got the params without the load function.